Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS, still issues with new pipewire
I use Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS, with all the new PipeWire installation (with Jack and PulseAudio facilities).
It is work, yes. BUT...
As I use Jack Mixer and Calf Studio Gear (to get full control of the downmixing from surround sound to stereo standard audio to my external amplifier and I process the dynamic of the sound to win the war against the noisy environment of my house).
In that line, I discovered the following problems I don't have any clue how to fix:

I have to manually disconnect some automatic connections between audio apps and the final audio stage showed by qwgraph and/or qjackctl (the box named "Built-in Audio Pro"). Before, without pipewire on 22.04.4 LTS, it wasn't this way.

I absolutely lost any surround sound capability! Now, any audio app (let's say: MPV Player) has only stereo standard outputs (Left and Right), even when it is playing a 5.1 surround sound file. I have all the surround channels mixed to stereo "inside" those apps. The same is with VLC, OcenAudio, SMP Player, Adobe Audition and the "speaker-test" command line (which there is no way to connect to the box named "Built-in Audio Pro 2" which is the connecting point of any audio input to be processed prior the last audio stage). Even the fact I don't lose any audio channels, I cannot to control those channels individually (as I used to make with Jack Mixer). So, If I don' want to hear some of the original surround channels, now I cannot silent any! With the old 22.04.4 LTS, I could get real surround sound from those apps, and I could manually control each channel individually with Jack Mixer.

I have to manually silent the sound monitor when I use the internal microphone of my laptop (HP 250-G5), when I want to record from it. If I don't do it... I just get a very ugly feedback!!! Also, I have to manually silent it when I record audio from any other source (internal or external), because I can hear all the environment audio captured by the microphone. Of course, it isn't the idea. Before, on 22.04.4 LTS, it wasn't this way.


So... Any idea to fix those 3 issues? ???

I found this solution helps. Hope this helps:
# Move the content of that two folder
mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse-bak
mv ~/.local/state/wireplumber ~/.local/state/wireplumber-bak
# Reboot the computer
sudo reboot

# Test if MPV works

# If everything works, remove the folder
rm -rf ~/.config/pulse-bak
rm -rf ~/.local/state/wireplumber-bak


Link only answers are discouraged. Please summarize the link contents in your answer.

The reason why I add github link because it would provide not only the solution that works for me but also allow other people to view other solution if this one doesn't work.
